# Using selectors in asm with VS2010

Tags: assembly

I have an old 16 bit assembler application that I would like to port to 32 bit. The problem is that it makes heavy use of segments ds, es and gs. So I can't use a flat model. So I could port those to selectors.

Can VS2010 support selectors in a user level application in 32 bit mode?

Comment: There is no flat memory model in 16-bit code.  You don't mess with segment registers in 32-bit code.  Clearly you'll have to rewrite the code.

Comment: 32 bit mode does not use segments it uses selectors. The 16 bit mode application doesn't use flat memory. It uses ES, GS, FS and for 32 bit mode those would be selectors. All I need to know is if vs2010 asm can use selectors (again, not segment registers).

Comment: You can write assembly code which uses selectors, of course, if that is really all you want to know. You can choose to ignore the additional information that the code will not run in Windows

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing two different terms. In REAL mode, the x86 uses segment registers and calculates a 20-bit address like this:

```
address = (segment_register << 4) + Offset
```

In PROTECTED mode (both 16-bit and 32-bit), the segment registers hold selectors to 64k/4GB blocks of memory and the address is calculated as:

```
address = selector_table[segment_register] + offset
```

In operating systems which use 32-bit and 64-bit protected mode, the OS typically keeps ES=DS=GS=SS and uses only the 32 or 64-bit offset to address memory.

If your code relies on real mode address calculations, then it will need to be completely rewritten for protected mode. If however, it was written for 16-bit protected mode, then it will still need significant changes, but fewer than the first case.

To go back to your question - VS2010 doesn't limit how you write the code, the OS does. Changing the value of the segment registers in protected mode can cause privilege violations. Also, segment overrides (e.g. ES:[DI]) are unnecessary since all of the segment registers contain the same value.

Comment: Actually there is a flat model in 16-bit code. All you have to do is go into protected mode, set the granularity to 4K then go back to real mode then use the 32 bit registers to access the memory. It is a little trick we used to use in the BIOS to quickly test all of memory.

Comment: Here is the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245108/is-there-an-api-for-win32-which-will-allow-me-to-use-es-gs-fs