# Is there an API for Win32 which will allow me to use ES, GS, FS?

Tags: winapi, assembly, x86, cpu-registers, memory-segmentation

I would like to use ES, FS, and GS in an assembler program to allow me to have 3 separate address spaces.

Is there a Win32 API which will setup the LDT and give me the values for the appropriate selectors?

Comment: I think you're confusing segments with address spaces. Even if you manage to set segment registers to different selectors pointing to different segments, these segments will still reside in the same virtual address space. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: By "Address Space" I mean separate segments of memory. For example, MOV AX,ES:[BX] would move from different "space" than MOV AX,GS:[BX] because ES and GS would contain different selectors. What I'm trying to accomplish is to port my 16 bit app to a 32 bit app but my 16 bit app uses ES, FS and GS to access 3 different 64K areas of memory.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is: yes, but.

The API you want is actually in the NT kernel and is called NtSetLdtEntries. There isn't a header for it. There isn't any documentation for it. The stubs are in ntdll.lib, which isn't part of the SDK. You have to do what I did and grope around among reverse engineering sites and manually bind things until I could make it work.

There's worse. You can't use GS, as Windows uses it internally; whenever you make a system call, it'll arbitrarily set it to 0 (and I *think* it may also randomly set it to 0 on interrupts). If you try to debug a program using GS, Windows will set it to 0 on breakpoints!

ES and FS are fine. I think.

Here is an undocumented file I wrote that uses all this stuff. If you're brave, you may be able to extract enough information from it to do something useful. Good luck...

http://lbw.git.sourceforge.net/git/gitweb.cgi?p=lbw/lbw;a=blob;f=src/syscalls/thread.cc;hb=a3b44871bd89009e644894431cbc6534fe033369

Comment: Is it possible to use NtSetLdtEntries on running threads? If not, i'd assume SetThreadContext function would be easier to use.

Comment: My software currently runs in 16 bit mode and I make heavy use of GS. But the program sometimes crashes when running in an XP 16 bit window. Do you think this same bug exists in 16 bit mode?

Comment: Don't know, TBH. I believe that XP 16-bit mode is a complete virtualised environment, which means that all bets are off. You might try stepping through your code with windbg and see if GS keeps getting reset to 0.

Comment: ES is probably *not* fine; it's used implicitly by `rep stos` and `rep movs`, which compilers or C libraries sometimes to inline a small or medium memset or memcpy of known size.  (And GCC used to inline `rep cmpsb` for short strcmp in some cases, although it's slow so GCC doesn't do that anymore.)

Comment: In 32-bit x86 Windows, FS:0 is expected to point at the Thread Information Block (TIB). It's undocumented but widely known and used, among others, by Microsoft's own C RTL. Not sure which parts of the API will break if it suddenly doesn't.